# How to back up Visualforce Pages?

Tags: visualforce, backup

I manage a couple of customer orgs and on each of those there are a couple of Visualforce Pages. They represent forms like contracts or invoices or other pages that are rendered as a PDF and sent to their customers.

I wonder - what is a good backup strategy for Visualforce Pages? Or how do I make a backup for them in the first place?

Sometimes they are changed by me. Most of the time the users change them. Everyone who is somewhat proficient in understanding Visualforce and comfortable enough in making changes to them does so at some point.

Sometimes I have my own access - most of the time I'm just being granted access through a managed package. Especially the latter is a big problem. Also they don't have any sandboxes at all or even if they do they are totally outdated.

I just want to make sure that accidental changes can be reverted. Salesforce Support is of no help as you have to be premium something before they lift a finger in situations like this. And of course most of them aren't premium. And now I'm searching for a way to mitigate these risks. Any good advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all of Salesforce customization, Visualforce pages are metadata that you can retrieve via API. You could build something that connects to the org, takes a snapshot, and then commits to Git. This is a fairly complicated process, so there are many vendors that have jumped in to offer this service. A [google search](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=salesforce%20metadata%20backup%20tool) of `Salesforce Metadata Backup` returns many options on the first page including Spanning, Own Backup, Blue Canvas, and Gearset. I'd suggest you look at the options out there and choose the one that works best for you.

As an aside, most orgs approach this problem with a deployment strategy that includes always building and testing in a sandbox and using some kind of repository to keep track of your org's metadata.

Comment: As I don't have any sandboxes and mostly no access an app would be a good choice - sadly that's not a decision I can make. I did a lot of research in the last few hours so maybe something like Ant or the Force.com CLI would be a second best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use github or gitlab for backup.

For more info refer: [Git and GitHub Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/git-and-git-hub-basics)

Also, refer this video: [Getting Started with Git on Salesforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DsbLEXdv7s)

Comment: I'm not sure how I am supposed to create a backup with Git. Versioning is hard since I don't gave access to those orgs. And even if I would version everything I could still only do it if things have been changed. And I don't know if things changed - like basically everything that needs to be backed up.